# Add Image To Filterable ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a searchable listview which filters results when the editable search box has text entered which is great, I'm struggling to add images to my single row so that each row will have a thumbnail image, title and description (thus far it has title and description only, no image), please see part of my code below:

```
    int[] images={R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, 
        R.drawable.image03, R.drawable.image04, 
        R.drawable.image05, R.drawable.image06,
        R.drawable.image07, R.drawable.image08, 
        R.drawable.image09, R.drawable.image10, 
        R.drawable.image11};

ArrayList<SomeThing> arraylist = new ArrayList<SomeThing>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

    rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11"};

    Resources res=getResources();
    myTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    myDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++)
    {
        SomeThing st= new SomeThing(myDescriptions[i],myTitles[i]);
        arraylist.add(st);
```

The XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageThumb"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:src="@drawable/list_beer_amstel" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/description"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
     android:layout_below="@+id/title"
     android:text="Description"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageThumb"
     android:text="Title"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: To Answer My Question In Case Someone Experiences The Same Problem:

In my ListAdapter class I added:

public class ViewHolder {
     ImageView photo;

AND 

holder.photo= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageThumb);